# Improving the dll missing error message

Tags: c++, qt, dll, bonjour

I have a program written in QT that works just fine. However it has an indirect dependency on dnssd.dll since a dll loaded by the program uses bonjour. If bonjour is not installed on the machine running the program it will say

> The program can't start because dnssd.dll is missing from your
>   computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix the problem.

I'm not loading this dll via `LoadLibrary` or otherwise. I linked the binary against the stub so it's loaded automatically before `int main`.

Obviously reinstalling the program does not fix the problem. For me it clearly says I need to install bonjour, but for most users this is extremly cryptic.

I would rather have this error message be something more informative such as "Bonjour needs to be installed for this application to work properly, go to [insert-url-here] to download it."

Is there a way to detect when a dll fails to load loke this and give a better error message?

Comment: Why don't you package Bonjour in the installer (can't say how without knowing what kind of installer you're using), or something similar?

Comment: Nice idea. People tend to uninstall it since they don't know what it is. Also it's a hassle and will create a more complicated and fragile installer. It has to take to accound bonjour is already installed, etc.

Comment: So, you prefer a more complicated and fragile application instead? Good installer frameworks provide robust solutions for most of these problems. This is not an unsolved problem.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes yes I do. My experience with installers is to keep it as simple as possible. Installers are very hard to test and should basically just copy the files to a folder. This is pretty much how Android does it and the Windows 8 store also, and a install virtually never fails there. We in the windows desktop world have lot to learn from this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set it to delay load, then as early as possible (before you cause loading to happen), try to load it yourself (with LoadLibrary) and report the problem.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/151kt790.aspx

Comment: so basically you're saying there is no way to detect when a dll that was linked against a stub fails to load?

Comment: If you let the load happen automatically, I don't think so, but if you just change a link setting and then add a few lines of code, then yes, it is possible.

Comment: You don't actually need to do the calls through the GetProcAddress or anything like that.  You are going to load just to check that the library is there -- then you call functions as you normally do knowing that the load process will succeed -- Delay Load just moves the LoadLibrary done by the runtime to when you actually use the DLL.